# Swift - React on "@" when pressing the keyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, textview, keyboard, mention

I want to call a function every time, whenever the user clicks on the "@" character on the keyboard.

Currently, I am using following approach

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here
   if (textView.text.contains("@") {
      doSomething()
   }
}
```

However, the code above doesn't work for me, because my text view will contain characters like @. This means, after having @ at least once in my text view, it will call the doSomething() function every time when I type something on the keyboard. Is there another way to check the input of the user?

Comment: Instead check `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`. Check `replacementString`? And check if you are already `doingSomething()`, just in case?

Answer (score 1):

instead of checking in textViewDidChange move to shouldChangeCharactersIn

```
func textField(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if (textView.text.contains"@") { // Already have @ value
        doSomething()
    }
    if (string == "@") { // user input char
        doSomething()
    }
    return true
}
```

Refer => https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618630-textview